# using htaccess to update browser default mod_rewrite string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have what I know is a stupid question but the answers on SO and elsewhere d not show me how this should be done.

I have a .htaccess Mod_rewrite which takes the string and uses it as a value in `index.php?nm=<value>` as shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pagenm=$1 [QSA]
```

I want to set htaccess to show my page even if no `pagenm` value is set by the URI, for example: `www.mywebsite.com/` does load perfectly well because the index.php page has a catch rule for if no `pagenm` value is given to use the default in-page value, but what I want is that **the browser URL is updated** *(hopefully without refreshing,redirecting, loading the page twice)*:

If no value is given, then htaccess rewrites to `welcome` so that:

```
 www.mywebsite.com
```

will always be displayed in the browser as

```
 www.mywebsite.com/welcome
```

I have tried `DirectoryIndex welcome` but this does not update the URL.

Comment: This is by definition a redirect, but since the server is handling the redirect, you don't really load the page twice. You get headers sent back from the server, and the browser pings the new address and hits it. Something like `Redirect "/" "/welcome"` should suffice. Another method is to rewrite history using JS, but thats a lot of effort for not taking a redirect into account.

Comment: how would I tell htaccess to I present the default `index` page as a mod_rewrite `/welcome` and reload, if no mod_rewrite string was present? as long as the final PHP page doesn't load twice was what I was looking to avoid. Cheers

Comment: I've just edited the comment, while you asked :)

Comment: The answer below adds 302 (Found). A good addition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if landing page redirect to /welcome
RewriteRule ^/?$ /welcome [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pagenm=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, I was unsure of the `^/?$` syntax for an empty string check. Many thanks as ever, anubhava!!